# How to calculate accurecy measures for "OneVsRestClassifier" classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I have a multiclass classification problem, the code bellow can classify the data at the multiclass level.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis as QDA


iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Binarize the output
y_bin = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes = y_bin.shape[1]

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(QDA())
y_score = cross_val_predict(clf, X, y, cv=10 ,method='predict_proba')
```

How Can I calculate the performance measures, listed below, of this classifier using the above code?

```
accuracy 
specificity
sensitivity
presison
mcc
f1
Recall
```

thank you..

Comment: What exactly was the purpose of a whole bunch of code for plotting the ROC curve, which has nothing to do with the question? (removed)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
```

In this case from what I understand, `y_test` is what you defined as `y` and `y_pred` can be easily calculated via:

```
y_pred = clf.predict(X)
```

You can find further information regarding metrics [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#classification-metrics) and some explinations in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) just remember for multilabel classes, the concepts of true negative and true positive should be understood differently.